# Multiple Selection and Drag in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, drag-and-drop, flex4.5, multipleselection

How to develope UI like [Elixir](http://visunetdemos.demos.ibm.com/diagramdemos/bpmeditor/bpmeditor.html#) in which we can select multiple objects and drag.
we can select items by ctrl+click or from selectionBox.

I'm using canvas and adding some custom components. I wanted to rearrange by Select multiple and dragging, Select multiple and removing etc.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3):

Here I can give you a simple starting point.

But, before that, **I didn't spend much time on this component. Please refer it just as an example.** You may want to write your own.

The following component uses an extra `Canvas` called `selectionLayer` for the multiple drag. When you select an item, item is removed from the main `Canvas` and added to `selectionLayer`. If you drag, it calls `selectionLayer.startDrag()` so that everything in the layer will move together. When drag completes it checks the changed x,y position of the layer (because the child components actually didn't move; the `selectionLayer` did) and applies it to the dragged components while moving `selectionLayer` to original position`(0,0)`.

DraggableCanvas.as:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    import mx.containers.Canvas;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;

    public class DraggableCanvas extends Canvas
    {
        protected var selectionLayer:Canvas;
        protected var isDragging:Boolean;

        public function DraggableCanvas()
        {
            super();
            isDragging = false;
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
        }

        protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, stage_mouseDownHandler);
        }

        protected function stage_mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (!isChildOf(event.target as DisplayObject))
                deselectAll();
        }

        override public function addChildAt(child:DisplayObject, index:int):DisplayObject
        {
            if (child is UIComponent)
            {
                UIComponent(child).addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, child_mouseDownHandler);
                UIComponent(child).addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, child_mouseUpHandler);
            }
            return super.addChildAt(child, index);
        }

        override protected function createChildren():void
        {
            super.createChildren();
            selectionLayer = new Canvas();
            selectionLayer.percentWidth = selectionLayer.percentHeight = 100;
            selectionLayer.alpha = 0.5;
            super.addChildAt(selectionLayer, 0);
        }

        protected function child_mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var target:UIComponent = event.currentTarget as UIComponent;

            if (!isSelected(target))
            {
                if (!event.ctrlKey)
                    deselectExcept(target);
                select(target);
                target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, child_mouseMoveHandler);
            }
            else
            {
                if (event.ctrlKey)
                    deselect(target);
                else
                    target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, child_mouseMoveHandler);
            }
        }

        protected function child_mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var target:UIComponent = event.currentTarget as UIComponent;

            selectionLayer.startDrag();
            isDragging = true;

            target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, child_mouseMoveHandler);
        }

        protected function child_mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var target:UIComponent = event.currentTarget as UIComponent;

            target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, child_mouseMoveHandler);

            if (isDragging)
            {
                if (target.parent == selectionLayer)
                {
                    selectionLayer.stopDrag();
                    isDragging = false;

                    for (var i:int = 0; i < selectionLayer.numChildren; i++)
                    {
                        var child:UIComponent = selectionLayer.getChildAt(i) as UIComponent;
                        child.move(child.x + selectionLayer.x, child.y + selectionLayer.y);
                    }

                    selectionLayer.move(0,0);
                }
            }
        }

        private function isSelected(target:DisplayObject):Boolean
        {
            return target.parent == selectionLayer;
        }

        private function isChildOf(obj:DisplayObject):Boolean
        {
            var p:DisplayObject = obj.parent;
            while (p)
            {
                if (p == this)
                    return true;
                p = p.parent;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private function select(target:DisplayObject):void
        {
            if (isSelected(target))
                return;
            super.removeChild(target);
            selectionLayer.addChild(target);
        }

        private function deselect(target:DisplayObject):void
        {
            if (!isSelected(target))
                return;
            selectionLayer.removeChild(target);
            super.addChild(target);
        }

        private function deselectExcept(target:DisplayObject):void
        {
            var children:Array = selectionLayer.getChildren();
            for each (var child:DisplayObject in children)
            {
                if (target != child)
                    deselect(child);
            }
        }

        private function deselectAll():void
        {
            deselectExcept(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns="*"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <DraggableCanvas width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Panel x="10" y="10"/>
        <mx:Panel x="150" y="10"/>
        <mx:Panel x="300" y="10"/>
    </DraggableCanvas>

</s:Application>
```

One more suggestion is, since you are using Flex 4.5, subclassing `SkinnableDataContainer` or `ListBase` is also recommended. Those components with ItemRenderer provide nice functionalities. But if you are not familiar with spark components, please never mind.

Comment: can u post some examples related to `SkinnableDataContainer` or `ListBase` I'm curious.

Comment: @SanthoshNayak I will go away for this weekend. However when I get back, I will work on it :')

Comment: @SanthoshNayak Okay, the example is ready. May I send you the project archive file? There are a couple of files, and I think it is better to send those files in archive than pasting them here.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by reading and studying an open-source app that provides the core functionality that Elixir does. That project is [ObjectHandles](http://www.objecthandles.com/)